# Getting relative links between two paths

Tags: shell, files, zsh, symlink

Say I have two paths: `<source_path>` and `<target_path>`. I would like my shell (zsh) to automatically find out if there is a way to represent `<target_path>` from `<source_path>` as a relative path.

E.g. Let's assume

- `<source_path>` is `/foo/bar/something`
- `<target_path>` is `/foo/hello/world`

The result would be `../../hello/world`

### Why I need this:

I need  like to create a symbolic link from `<source_path>` to `<target_path>` using a **relative** symbolic link whenever possible, since otherwise our samba server does not show the file properly when I access these files on the network from Windows (I am not the sys admin, and don't have control over this setting)

Assuming that `<target_path>` and `<source_path>` are absolute paths, the following creates a symbolic link **pointing to an absolute path**.

```
ln -s <target_path> <source_path>
```

so it does not work for my needs. I need to do this for hundreds of files, so I can't just manually fix it.

Any shell built-ins that take care of this?

Comment: You can use `symlinks` to convert absolute links to relative.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas how? Could you post an answer explaining?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the `symlinks` command to convert absolute paths to relative:

```
/tmp$ mkdir -p 1/{a,b,c} 2
/tmp$ cd 2
/tmp/2$ ln -s /tmp/1/* .
/tmp/2$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane 8 Jul 31 16:32 a -> /tmp/1/a/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane 8 Jul 31 16:32 b -> /tmp/1/b/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane 8 Jul 31 16:32 c -> /tmp/1/c/
```

We've got absolute links, let's convert them to relative:

```
/tmp/2$ symlinks -cr .
absolute: /tmp/2/a -> /tmp/1/a
changed:  /tmp/2/a -> ../1/a
absolute: /tmp/2/b -> /tmp/1/b
changed:  /tmp/2/b -> ../1/b
absolute: /tmp/2/c -> /tmp/1/c
changed:  /tmp/2/c -> ../1/c
/tmp/2$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane 6 Jul 31 16:32 a -> ../1/a/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane 6 Jul 31 16:32 b -> ../1/b/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane 6 Jul 31 16:32 c -> ../1/c/
```

#### References

- [symlinks man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/symlinks)

Comment: Thanks Stephane. This solves the root problem, so I have accepted. That said, it would be great to have something (e.g. a zsh function) that takes two paths (source and target) and outputs the relative path from source to target (no symbolic links here). That would solve the question asked in the title as well.

Comment: @user815423426, terdon [has answered that part](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85069/22565)

Answer (score 56):

Try using [`realpath` command](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/realpath) (part of GNU `coreutils`; *>=8.23*), e.g.:

```
realpath --relative-to=/foo/bar/something /foo/hello/world
```

<sup>If you're using macOS, install GNU version via: `brew install coreutils` and use `grealpath`.</sup>

Note that both paths need to exist for the command to be successful. If you need the relative path anyway even if one of them does not exist then add the -m switch.

For more examples, see [Convert absolute path into relative path given a current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2564634/55075).

Comment: I get `realpath: unrecognized option '--relative-to=.'` :( realpath version 1.19

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You need to use GNU/Linux version of `realpath`. If you're on macOS, install via: `brew install coreutils`.

Comment: no, I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I'm on `realpath (GNU coreutils) 8.26` where the parameter is present. See: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/realpath Double check that you're not using an alias (e.g. run as `\realpath`), and how you can install the version from the `coreutils`.

Comment: Seems [realpath on Ubuntu 14.04 is outdated indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory-using-bash#comment64414270_28523143), and the only way is [rebuild coreutil manually](https://askubuntu.com/q/736569/253474)

Comment: Note that `--relative-to=…` expects a directory and DOES NOT check. That means that you end up with an extra "../" if you request a path relative to a file.

Answer (score 10):

I think this python solution (taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7305217/1081936)) is also worth mentioning. Add this to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
relpath() python -c 'import os.path, sys;\
  print os.path.relpath(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])' "$1" "${2-$PWD}"
```

You can then do, for example:

```
$ relpath /usr/local/share/doc/emacs /usr/local/share/fonts
../doc/emacs
```

Answer (score 7):

There are not any shell builtins to take care of this. I found [a solution on
Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12498485/1655874) though. I have
copied the solution here with slight modifications and marked this answer as
community wiki.

```
relpath() {
    # both $1 and $2 are absolute paths beginning with /
    # $1 must be a canonical path; that is none of its directory
    # components may be ".", ".." or a symbolic link
    #
    # returns relative path to $2/$target from $1/$source
    source=$1
    target=$2

    common_part=$source
    result=

    while [ "${target#"$common_part"}" = "$target" ]; do
        # no match, means that candidate common part is not correct
        # go up one level (reduce common part)
        common_part=$(dirname "$common_part")
        # and record that we went back, with correct / handling
        if [ -z "$result" ]; then
            result=..
        else
            result=../$result
        fi
    done

    if [ "$common_part" = / ]; then
        # special case for root (no common path)
        result=$result/
    fi

    # since we now have identified the common part,
    # compute the non-common part
    forward_part=${target#"$common_part"}

    # and now stick all parts together
    if [ -n "$result" ] && [ -n "$forward_part" ]; then
        result=$result$forward_part
    elif [ -n "$forward_part" ]; then
        # extra slash removal
        result=${forward_part#?}
    fi

    printf '%s\n' "$result"
}
```

You can use this function like so:

```
source=/foo/bar/something
target=/foo/hello/world
ln -s "$(relpath "$source" "$target")" "$source"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
# Prints out the relative path between to absolute paths. Trivial.
#
# Parameters:
# $1 = first path
# $2 = second path
#
# Output: the relative path between 1st and 2nd paths
relpath() {
    local pos="${1%%/}" ref="${2%%/}" down=''

    while :; do
        test "$pos" = '/' && break
        case "$ref" in $pos/*) break;; esac
        down="../$down"
        pos=${pos%/*}
    done

    echo "$down${ref##$pos/}"
}
```

This is the simplest and most beautiful solution to the problem.

Also it should work on all bourne-like shells.

And the wisdom here is: there is absolutely no need for external utilities or even complicated conditions. A couple prefix/suffix substitutions and a while loop is all you need to get just about anything done on bourne-like shells.

Also available via PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/CtTfvime

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I found that to make it work in a `Makefile` I needed to add a pair of double quotes to the line `pos=${pos%/*}` (and, of course, semicolons and backslashes at the end of everyline).

Comment: Idea is not bad but, in current version plenty of cases don't work: `relpath /tmp /tmp`, `relpath /tmp /tmp/a`, `relpath /tmp/a /`. In add, you forget to mention that all paths must be absolute AND canonicalized (i.e. `/tmp/a/..` does not work)

Answer (score 2):

I found it curious that it wasn't mentioned yet: the case when one path is a child of a parent path, there's a [simple expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) that doesn't involve forking calls (ex realpath). @Arto mentioned this kindof, but the more complicated and general approach where you have to go up and down.

```bash
PARENT=/my/absolute/path/to/dir/
CHILD=/my/absolute/path/to/dir/subdir/grandchilddir/myfile
RELPATH=${CHILD##"$PARENT"} # subdir/grandchilddir/myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to write a [bash script](https://github.com/jjqq2013/bash-scripts/blob/master/common/relpath) to do this reliably (and of course without verifying file existence).

Usage

```
relpath <symlink path> <source path>
```

Returns a relative source path.

example:

```
#/a/b/c/d/e   ->  /a/b/CC/DD/EE       ->  ../../CC/DD/EE
relpath /a/b/c/d/e   /a/b/CC/DD/EE

#./a/b/c/d/e   ->  ./a/b/CC/DD/EE       ->  ../../CC/DD/EE
relpath ./a/b/c/d/e  ./a/b/CC/DD/EE
```

both get
`../../CC/DD/EE`

---

To have a quick test you can run

```
curl -sL https://github.com/jjqq2013/bash-scripts/raw/master/common/relpath | bash -s -- --test
```

result: a list of test

```
/a             ->  /                 ->  .
/a/b           ->  /                 ->  ..
/a/b           ->  /a                ->  .
/a/b/c         ->  /a                ->  ..
/a/b/c         ->  /a/b              ->  .
/a/b/c         ->  /a/b/CC           ->  CC
/a/b/c/d/e     ->  /a                ->  ../../..
/a/b/c/d/e     ->  /a/b              ->  ../..
/a/b/c/d/e     ->  /a/b/CC           ->  ../../CC
/a/b/c/d/e     ->  /a/b/CC/DD/EE     ->  ../../CC/DD/EE
./a            ->  ./                ->  .
./a/b          ->  ./                ->  ..
./a/b          ->  ./a               ->  .
./a/b/c        ->  ./a               ->  ..
./a/b/c        ->  ./a/b             ->  .
./a/b/c        ->  ./a/b/CC          ->  CC
./a/b/c/d/e    ->  ./a               ->  ../../..
./a/b/c/d/e    ->  ./a/b/CC          ->  ../../CC
./a/b/c/d/e    ->  ./a/b/CC/DD/EE    ->  ../../CC/DD/EE
/a             ->  /x                ->  x
/a/b           ->  /x                ->  ../x
/a/b/c         ->  /x                ->  ../../x
/a             ->  /x/y              ->  x/y
/a/b           ->  /x/y              ->  ../x/y
/a/b/c         ->  /x/y              ->  ../../x/y
/x             ->  /a                ->  a
/x             ->  /a/b              ->  a/b
/x             ->  /a/b/c            ->  a/b/c
/x/y           ->  /a                ->  ../a
/x/y           ->  /a/b              ->  ../a/b
/x/y           ->  /a/b/c            ->  ../a/b/c
./a a/b/c/d/e  ->  ./a a/b/CC/DD/EE  ->  ../../CC/DD/EE
/x x/y y       ->  /a a/b b/c c      ->  ../a a/b b/c c
```

---

BTW, if you want to use this script without saving it and you trust this script, then you have two ways to to this with bash trick.

Import `relpath` as a bash function by following command. (Require bash 4+)

```
source <(curl -sSL https://github.com/jjqq2013/bash-scripts/raw/master/common/relpath)
```

or call the script on-the-fly like with curl bash combo.

```
curl -sSL https://github.com/jjqq2013/bash-scripts/raw/master/common/relpath | bash -s -- /a/b/c/d/e /a/b/CC/DD/EE
```