# Can realpath command completely replaced by readlink command?

Tags: shell-script, shell, readlink

Given that `realpath` command does not exists on [every unix platform](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136527/214010), I would like to replace `realpath` with `readlink` command in order to make my shell script as cross-platform as possible.

The thing is that `realpath` has the `--relative-to` parameter which is necessary in my case:

```bsh
$ realpath bdd/full --relative-to bdd
full
```

on the other hand, `readlink` seems to provide only the main functionality of `realpath` command:

```bsh
$ readlink -f bdd/full
/home/user/bdd/full
```

After reading the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink), I couldn't find any parameter similar to `--relative-to`.

Have you any idea if `readlink` supports a `--relative-to`-like functionality and if it's not, is there any "clean" way to achive such thing using `readlink` or any other cross-platform command?

**UPDATE:**

In my case, `--relative-to` is necessary for logging purposes, in my shell script, the user passes two relative paths, the relative of the base folder and the relative path of the file on which the action will be performed. In order to print a more-human friendly log entry, I want to print the relative path of file from the base folder path.

I'm currently using the following function to achive my goal:

```bsh
get_relative_path () {
  if command -v realpath &> /dev/null
  then
    realpath --relative-to="${2-$PWD}" "$1"
  else
    python -c 'import os.path, sys;print os.path.relpath(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])' "$1" "${2-$PWD}"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Could you give us some more details on why you need this? `readlink` doesn't have any equivalent to `--relative-to`, but if you explain why you need it, we might be able to come up with a workaround.

Comment: There seems not to be any easy alternative to `realpath`: see, for instance https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85060/315749 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/2564634/10488700 on Stack Overflow

Comment: Your example gives the same output as say `basename PATH` - are you just trying to get the last element? or do you intend something else? Unfortunately this is a difficult problem to solve for large numbers of platforms - for instance on OSX readlink doesn't have -f option

Comment: @terdon check out the update for further details

Comment: @MrR basename is not enough in my case, file might be inside multiple sub-folders. You are right, I didn't know how difficult is to implement a cross-platform shell script :P

Comment: It's unusual to print relative filenames (given a specific file input)  ... for instance try `/bin/ls /bin/foo/nonexistant
ls: /bin/foo/nonexistant: No such file or directory` [they just give you back exactly what you entered].  Additionally what if you get given a path which is relative the current directory - e.g. `./mary/had/a/little/lamb/` or without the dotslash `mary/had/a/little/lamb` will this give sensible results to the user??

Comment: Relative paths are ambiguous: if a program tells you it is running in `a/` and using `../c/` and `../c/d/f`, how can you know whether they actually were `/x/y/a/`, `/x/y/c/` and `/x/y/c/f`, respectively, or `/w/z/a/`, `/w/z/c/` and `/w/z/c/f`? In other words, do you really need relative paths instead of absolute ones?